# Reacting on a finished Ember Data hasMany query

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use Ember 1.0.0-RC3 with Ember Data. I have the requirement to react ***efficiently*** when a *hasMany* relationship has been loaded successfully.

My domain model looks conceptually like this:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    fullName: DS.attr("string"),
    friends: DS.hasMany("App.Person")
});
```

I use Ember Data's default `DS.RESTAdapter`. Its default behavior is to load *hasMany* relationships on demand in one big batch request.

As `somePerson` can have lots of `friends`, receiving the `friends` relationship back from the server may take some time.

I would like to provide users of my web application visual feedback (e.g a spinner animation) during the time a `hasMany` relationship has been requested and until the server responses with a result.

How can I accomplish this requirement efficiently? Are there hooks that I can use to plug in my custom "`startedLoading`" and "`finishedLoading`" callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Try on a `bindAttr` in the handlebars view on the `friends.isLoaded` property:

```
<span {{bindAttr class="friends.isLoaded:loading:hide"}}></span>
```

For a more advanced processing yo can do a `Ember.observer` in the controller:

```
App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    watchFriends: Ember.observer(function(){
        var loaded = this.get('friends.isLoaded')
    }, 'friends.isLoaded')

})
```